# simple bash process substitution not working with kdiff3 and hexdump

Tags: bash, process, substitution, hexdump, kdiff3

I want to kdiff3 the *hexdumped* versions of two binary files.  At first I was using an amateurish two step process of hexdump, then kdiff3.  However, I recently learned about bash process substitution.  For some reason it doesn't work for my case, though.

file1 contents  `this is file1`

file2 contents  `this is file2`

Issuing  `kdiff3 <(hexdump file1) <(hexdump file2)`  results in kdiff3 saying the files are binary equal which is categorically untrue.

What gives?  Are not all programs able to handle this kind of input?

Of course  `kdiff3 file1 file2`  shows the correct result (that they differ) inside kdiff3.

Comment: `kdiff3` probably requires the ability to seek within the input files; pipes are not seekable.

Comment: Back to the amateurish two step process it is!  Thanks.